# Can we achieve SSO between a Native Application and Web Application Registered in B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If we develop a native application for B2C and after user logs in he clicks a link which is a web application with B2C same tenant. And if the SSO settings in B2C are set to tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso

Can we achieve SSO i.e. a user is not asked to re-enter credentials?

Comment: I would say no because your application does not share the access token with the webapp. does that make sense for you ?

Comment: yes it does but if i use the same application which acts as both Web Application and Native Application i.e in the Registered application toggle the native client to yes . will it not worki.e SSO ? SSO Docs just mention that you can set it to tenant level or policy level and application using the same policy should get SSO and hence the confusion

Comment: Yeah but but you're switching from a native app to a browser (web) app so you can't pass the token even if the token is valid for both app. If you find a way to pass the token securely between the mobile app to the webapp if would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Independent of how the different applications are registered with the Azure AD B2C tenant and what the SSO options are set to, the SSO session is implemented by a browser cookie/s that is maintained by Azure AD B2C in the browser session.

So, if you can share the browser cookies between your native app and your web site on the same device, then you should experience SSO between the two apps.

Authentication libraries, such as [AppAuth for Android](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/), [AppAuth for iOS](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/), [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/tree/master) and [MSAL for iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc), implement the browser integration between your native app and Azure AD B2C for you. They also implement "the best current practice [which] is to perform the OAuth authorization request in an external user agent (typically the browser) rather than an embedded user agent (such as one implemented with web-views)."

It's a bit challenging to follow whether the native platforms do allow the browser cookies to be shared between apps and sites on the same device but I'll attempt to summarize my current understanding.

For Android, AppAuth and MSAL use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), which does allow the cookie data ("the cookie jar") to be shared so "users don't have to log in to sites [e.g. Azure AD B2C] they are already connected to".

For iOS 11, AppAuth and MSAL use [SFAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession), which does allow the cookie data to be shared but "users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent" to do so.

For iOS 10 and 9, AppAuth and MSAL use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller), which also does allow the cookie data to be shared.

Comment: thanks for the Detailed Explanation, that's answers  my question

Comment: @Chris Padgett So there is no way we could actually do sso between iOS app and webapp without selecting account in browser?

Comment: is there any new solution to this ? I am using same app registration and same user flow policy.